# React native windows support

Tags: react-native

As per React native documentation looks like mobile application on windows is not supported. Do you aware of such limitation ? Pls confirm Is there any other way by which we can support on Windows platform ?

Comment: what do you mean 'mobile application on windows' ?

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started